# Kafka := Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: No entry found for connection

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

while running kafka code getting

> 1) ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id =
>   c6426655-446f-4306-91ba-d78e68e05c15, runId =
>   420382c1-8558-45a1-b26d-f6299044fa04] terminated with error
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> 2)Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id =
>   c6426655-446f-4306-91ba-d78e68e05c15, runId =
>   420382c1-8558-45a1-b26d-f6299044fa04]"
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> 3)Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: null

sbt dependency

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.3"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.3"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.2.3" % "provided"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.1.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.1.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "2.1.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.2.3"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams-scala
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka-streams-scala" % "2.1.1"

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object demo1 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","c:\\hadoop\\")

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("My Spark Application")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp") // Necessary to work around a Windows bug in Spark 2.0.0; omit if you're not on Windows.
      .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "file:///C:/checkpoint")
      .getOrCreate

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    spark.conf.set("spark,sqlshuffle.partations","2")

    val df = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "162.244.80.189:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("group.id","test1")
      .option("subscribe", "demo11")
      .load()

    import spark.implicits._


    val dsStruc = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp").as[(String, String, Timestamp)]


    val abc = df.writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .start().awaitTermination()

    df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I have used the wrong library spark-sql-kafka library version (2.2.0 instead of 2.3.0). My successful  configuration is:

> org.apache.spark
>             spark-core_2.11
>             2.3.0            provided
>
> org.apache.spark
>             spark-sql_2.11             2.3.0
>
> org.apache.spark
>             spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11
>             2.3.0
>
> org.apache.kafka
>             kafka-clients
>             0.10.1.0

I hope it helps.
I got inspired by this post

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/222428/error-microbatchexecution-query-id-567e4e77-9457-4.html